# One query two MySQL servers

Tags: mysql, query

I have **two MySQL servers on different server computers**. Is it possible to execute single query like this:

`INSERT INTO database1.xxxxx SELECT table1.field1, table2.field1 FROM database2.xxxxx INNER JOIN ...`.

EDIT: I will make cron job witch will run this once a day. I don't need synchronization.

Comment: You can use FEDERATED tables for this, or possibly pt-archiver from the Percona Toolkit.

Comment: FEDERATED isn't the option to me, because it is very slow when I need to select like ~200k+ records.

Comment: Look at pt-archive. It may be suited for your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is cron job I ended up with:

I had to create database, where I store temp data:

`mysqldump -uuser -ppass database table1 -hhost | mysql -uuser -ppass database_copy && mysqldump -uuser -ppass database table2 -hhost | mysql -uuser -ppass database_copy`

`and etc`

and after copying all the needed data I run MySQL queries to process and insert data depending on my needs:

`mysql -e "INSERT INTO table3 SELECT fields... FROM database_copy INNER JOIN database_copy WHERE ...; QUERY 2; ..." -hhost -uuser -ppass`

**P.S.** I will confirm my own answer as correct, but feel free to add any easier or less complex way to do this, I will recheck your answer for sure.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in this scenario you have two remote MySQL server you need to have two connections.
MySQL does not support such a query wherein it connects to other server and get details, in my understanding no other RDBMS does this kind of thing.

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    SELECT ...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_name=expr, ... ]
```

**Conclusion:**
NO. You can't write such query on **Two** Mysql servers.

Comment: I kind of find this article after some searching - http://sqlwithmanoj.wordpress.com/2010/11/10/linked-server-in-ms-sql-server/, gave this to my server admin, he said he will look into it and I will post how it went if no one has any other sugestion.